# python: pandas .describe - how to put results into a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

pretty new to python and pandas in general. I have a dataframe that has 2 columns i want to analyze:

```
df2 = df1.query('debt == 1').groupby(['family_status'])['family_status'].describe()
```

This gives me the result of:

```
                  count unique                top freq
family_status                                         
civil partnership   388      1  civil partnership  388
divorced             85      1           divorced   85
married             931      1            married  931
unmarried           274      1          unmarried  274
widow / widower      63      1    widow / widower   63
```

which is a lot of information that i wanted to know - however, to do some additional analysis i'd like to be able to put these results by 'family_status' into variables - so, civil partnership, divorced, married, etc. or feed them into an ad-hoc function.
**Edit for clarity** - i want to have civil_partnership = the count (in this case 388) etc.
unsure how to proceed.

thanks for your time in advance,

Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to create a dictionary and call each `faimily_status` as a key in that dict. Since you've assigned your describe dataframe to `df2`:

```py
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)

d = {}
for status, count in zip(df2['family_status'], df2['count']):
    d[status] = count
```

This should result in something like

```
d = {
'civil partnership'  : 388 
'divorced'           :  85 
'married'            : 931 
'unmarried'          : 274
'widow / widower'    :  63 
}
```

edit:

`df2.count` invokes the `count` method -- syntax adjusted so that it calls the column, not the method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - the results aren't exactly what i was hoping for - i'm getting:
{'civil partnership': 5, 'divorced': 5, 'married': 5, 'unmarried': 5, 'widow / widower': 5}

Comment: hmm, you might be invoking a method with that syntax. do you get the same results if you replace `df2.count` with `df2['count']`?

Comment: oh yep - that works. thanks! that is confusing on my part because of how they are named. doh

Answer (score 2):

`.describe()` returns a normal dataframe, so you can assign it to amy variable and apply any dataframe methods in it.

And to select by index use `.ix`

Comment: Thanks for the response - i'm not sure i follow this comment:

"*And to select by index use .ix*